# Determining the version of v7 appcompat library

Tags: android

In Android, the v7 appcompat library apparently comes in different versions, according to:
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7

It isn't apparent though how Android determines the actual version of this library. It's a jar file and I'm not sure how the version information is stored in the jar file.

Comment: Those aren't different versions, they are different libraries.

Answer (score 0):

> It isn't apparent though how Android determines the actual version of this library

Android doesn't "determine the actual version of this library".

> It's a jar file

No, it is not. It is an AAR file consumed through a repository (or, for Eclipse users, an Android library project).

> and I'm not sure how the version information is stored in the jar file.

It is not stored in the JAR file. It is in the POM file in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: if your project imports more than one copy of `android-support-v4`, the build tools compare their checksums.  If they differ, the build halts.

Managing compatibility library versions can be a hassle.  I've developed an approach to help keep things straight.

Before I proceed, let's clear up some confusion about what `appcompat_v7` actually is.  It's an Android library project that contains the `android-support-v4` jar, plus some resources that are required by some of the classes in that jar.  Depending on what you're using the support library for, you may need the full project or you may only need the jar.  You can copy the jar from into your project, but I don't recommend it.

The remainder of this answer is Eclipse-centric.  YMMV.

You can avoid version conflicts if your libraries do not export the `android-support-v4` jar.  If your libraries export it, fix them.  If you're using third-party libraries that export it, demand they be fixed or ditch them for a more competent vendor.

I prefer that my own libraries and projects never contain a copy of the `android-support-v4` jar.  I just have them depend on `appcompat_v7` even if they don't need the resources it contains.  This makes it easier to keep track of which version of `android-support-v4` I'm building with.  To make it even easier, I like to rename the `appcompat_v7` project to include the actual version number from the SDK manager, e.g., `appcompat_v7_21.0.2`.

It used to be that Eclipse would always create a new copy of `appcompat_v7` whenever you created a new project that requires it.  If it already existed in the workspace, it would create a new copy and name it something like `appcompat_v7_2`.  I think this behavior depends on the SDK tools rather than Eclipse, because I noticed it change after upgrading my SDK.  It no longer creates another `appcompat_v7` if one already exists.  This can lead to your new apps building against an older version of the support lib, which is another reason I like to rename it to include the version number.